# How to convert a Scala anonymous trait implementation to Rust?

Tags: scala, rust

I'm having difficulty converting this Scala trait to Rust

```scala
trait Inject[A, B] {
  self =>

  def inject(input: A): B

  def project(input: B): Try[A]

  def contraMap[AA](inj: Inject[AA, A]): Inject[AA, B] = new Inject[AA, B] {
    override def inject(input: AA) = self.inject(inj.inject(input))

    override def project(input: B) = self.project(input).flatMap(i => inj.project(i))
  }

  def map[BB](inj: Inject[B, BB]): Inject[A, BB] = new Inject[A, BB] {
    override def inject(input: A) = inj.inject(self.inject(input))

    override def project(input: BB) = inj.project(input).flatMap(i => self.project(i))
  }

}
```

Here is my Rust equivalent

```rust
pub trait Injection<A, B> {
    fn inject(input: A) -> B;
    fn project(input: B) -> Result<A, InjectionError>;
    fn contraMap<AA>(input: Injection<AA, A>) -> Injection<AA, B>;
    fn map<BB>(input: Injection<B, BB>) -> Injection<A, BB>;
}

pub struct InjectionError {
    msg: String,
}
```

I am getting:

```
error[E0038]: the trait `Injection` cannot be made into an object
 --> src/main.rs:4:5
  |
4 |     fn contraMap<AA>(input: Injection<AA, A>) -> Injection<AA, B>;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Injection` cannot be made into an object
  |
  = note: method `inject` has no receiver
  = note: method `project` has no receiver
  = note: method `contraMap` has no receiver
  = note: method `map` has no receiver
```

If I add a `self` reference, I still get the same error:

```rust
pub trait Injection<A, B> {
    fn inject(&self, input: A) -> B;
    fn project(&self, input: B) -> Result<A, InjectionError>;
    fn contraMap<AA>(&self, input: Injection<AA, A>) -> Injection<AA, B>;
    fn map<BB>(&self, input: Injection<B, BB>) -> Injection<A, BB>;
}

pub struct InjectionError {
    msg: String,
}
```

I am not sure how I can instantiate an anonymous `Injection` like I am doing in Scala. What would be the idiomatic way of converting this Scala trait to Rust?

Comment: Please produce a [MCVE], you can use the Rust Playground to do so. You may also want to search your error message on Google, it's already appeared a lot of times on stackoverflow.

Comment: Currently, your definition of `Injection` contains four **static functions**. If you want to define methods, you need to specify the `self` parameter. I would recommend (re-)reading the chapter on method syntax: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch05-03-method-syntax.html

Comment: Generally, you won't have an easy time trying to directly translate Scala to Rust. It would be much easier to start by explaining what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rust, traits only describe behavior, not data. The compiler tells you your trait is not object-safe because you want to return anything that implements the trait, and that 'anything' has no single canonical known size at compile time.

You can `Box` your values to put them on the heap, or use references (which will require some scary lifetime juggling and be quite brittle, but avoid the allocation). You will also need to return a concrete type from `map` and `contraMap`. Look how Rust's [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/iterator.rs.html#479) trait does it: It returns a `Map` which is generic over the original iterator and the function type it maps, wraps both and implements `Iterator`.